# How to create array of class object inside the same class in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a query in Swift 3.0. I am calling a web service and getting an array of contacts from the server. I am creating a class Contacts:

```
Class Contacts: NSObject {
    var address : String?
    var email : String?
    var gender : String?
    var name : String?
    var id : String?
    var phone : String?

//var array to store class object

     var arrayOfContacts = [Contacts]()

        override init() {
            super.init()
        }
    }
```

I need to access all the objects store in arrayOfContacts from somewhere in my code.

How should I create such a functionality or I am on the wrong way?

Comment: do you want display contacts immediately or later after server response? do you want to access these contacts array from anywhere or just one class?

Answer (score 3):

Two ways

**way 1:**

Declare your `arrayOfContacts` as static

```
class Contacts: NSObject {
    var address : String?
    var email : String?
    var gender : String?
    var name : String?
    var id : String?
    var phone : String?

    //var array to store class object

    static var arrayOfContacts = [Contacts]()
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

And access it as

```
print(Contacts.arrayOfContacts)
```

**Way 2:**

If you want your contacts to be `singleton`  use

```
class Contacts: NSObject {
    var address : String?
    var email : String?
    var gender : String?
    var name : String?
    var id : String?
    var phone : String?
    var arrayOfContacts = [Contacts]()
    static var sharedInstance = Contacts()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Then access it as

```
Contacts.sharedInstance.arrayOfContacts
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

actually you can create an array of objects in same class but you must not it in same class, so I provide code how to do it

```
        Class Contacts: NSObject {
            var address : String?
            var email : String?
            var gender : String?
            var name : String?
            var id : String?
            var phone : String?

            override init() {
                super.init()
            }

           static func arrayOfObject(_ array: NSArray)-> [Contacts] {
             var contactsArr: [Contacts] = []
             for data in array {
                let cont = Contacts(...)//init all properties
                contactsArr.append(cont)
            }
            return contactsArr
           }

        }
```

and call this method where you get your data

```
Contacts.arrayOfObject(<array of data>)
```

Comment: Am sorry but this is not the correct answer. The op has asked a way to access the arrayOfContacts variable he has created in Contacts class. The answer assumes that every time to get the array of contacts I need to pass a nsarray of objects! How about accessing already saved data then ? Write another function for that? I wonder which design pattern being referred here before making statement that u are not supposed to create array of objects in same class!! Infact the local declaration of arrayOfContacts makes the property inaccessible outside! This is not what was asked!

Comment: @gagan-ios : read my comment above. The answer u have accepted is not the correct solution to what u have asked for. I don't see any reason as to why u shouldnt create a array of objects in the same class. If that was true the whole concept of shared instance would not have existed in programming world. In shared instance u declare the static variable of same class to make it accessible outside n that's  a not wrong so is array of objects Think before u accept the answer. The above answer is misleading n completely defies the purpose with which the question was asked!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Singleton pattern for this.
Play with it in playground.

```
import Foundation

class Contacts: NSObject {
    var address : String?
    var email : String?
    var gender : String?
    var name : String?
    var id : String?
    var phone : String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        ContactSingleton.shared.arrayOfContacts.append(self)
    }
}

final class ContactSingleton {

    // MARK: Properties
    internal static let shared = ContactSingleton()
    internal var arrayOfContacts: [Contacts] = []

    // MARK: - Initializer
    private init() { }

}

let contact1 = Contacts()
print(ContactSingleton.shared.arrayOfContacts.count) // 1

let contact2 = Contacts()
let contact3 = Contacts()
print(ContactSingleton.shared.arrayOfContacts.count) // 3
```